# Is it possible to get address of function that implement virtual

Tags: c++

I have address of virtual function in export table , is it possible to get implementation function address, that makes whole logic of virtual ?

---

Code sample:

this is virtual function that goes to export table

```
class CORE_API FArchive
{
public:
    virtual ~FArchive()
    {}
    virtual void messageboxer(char* messagetext){}
};
```

and this is virtual function implementation

```
class FArchiveFileReader : public FArchive
{
public:

    void messageboxer(char* messagetext)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, messagetext, "alert", MB_ICONERROR);
    }
};
```

So in export table goes only virtual - like that ?`messageboxer@FArchive@@UAEXPAD@Z`

If i go on that address(in memmory via debugger) i get this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/se3Tb.png - i dont see there nothing usefull, like jmp or call.
and this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmKgV.png is where function implementation is, is it connected somehow ? so i can calculate it.

Or having virtual function address from export table - is nothing, in terms of getting address of function(with actual logic) ?

If so - can someone give me an simple and good article describing on how to get address of actual function(not virtual).

P.S.
And sorry if i talk little strange, english isnt my common language, if you think that some place in my text is unclear, pls tell me where and i would try to explain better !

Hope someoe would help me

thx!

Comment: Is it possible to get Vtable index of the function using some info from Virtual function ? IF so - can someone explain me how to do that ?